# PyCharm configuration

Tags: python, pycharm

I started a python project and attempted to have it OOP.

I used a script to call function from classes, in the following way:

```
class Object(): 
    def function(input):
       print(input)
```

The command `Object.Object.function("example")` used to work fine.

I had to reinstall pycharm, and now when running the same code I get the error of not sending enough input.

This can be solved by changing the call to `Object.Object().function("example")`,

and the function definition to `def function(a,input):`

Where the variable a is never used. This however causes new problems when using libraries.

How can I use the previous configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.Object.function("example")` and `Object.Object().function("example")` are different beasts entirely. The first run invokes the method `function` on the class `Object.Object`, while in the latter, `Object.Object()` creates an instance of type `Object.Object` and invokes `function` on that instance (which fails as you must provide the instance itself as the first parameter to the method). It sounds like you are trying to make something like a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod),

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f(input):
        print(input)
```

for which both `A.f` and `A().f` will act as `print`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this: `TypeError: unbound method getArray() must be called with GetData instance as first argument (got str instance instead)` (GetData is the name of the object, getArray is the function), this is the reason I changed the code in the first place.

Comment: After rewriting some of the commands, `@staticmethod` appears to solve the problem. Thank you!